# Scrolling DataGridView per pixel

Tags: c#, winforms, reflection, datagridview

I am making a .NET 4 WinForms application which reads data from a database and displays rows in a DGV. However the number of rows is larger than maximum number of rows that can fit on screen at once. To display all data, I need to scroll the DGV automatically until the last row and update the data source after that in order to refresh the DGV.

I found it's easy to do that by simply incrementing `FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex` by one.
However the scrolling is too sharp. I would like it to scroll smoothly.

To do that, I have tried calling `ScrollRows` method directly. That method is not public so I had to use Reflection like this:

```
var scrollRows = dgv.GetType().GetMethod("ScrollRows", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
scrollRows.Invoke(dgv, new object[] { 1, -1, ScrollEventType.SmallIncrement });
```

I call this code from a `timer_Tick` method which is triggered every 20 ms.

The DGV scrolls smoothly but it doesn't draw any row below those which were visible at the beginning.

Is there any way I can make it scroll smoothly AND display data properly?

Comment: have you tried calling `Invalidate()` after scrolling?

Comment: @KingKing just did, `dgv.Invalidate()` acts the same as `dgv.Refresh()` would, resets the vertical scroll offset to 0.

Comment: It's hard to scroll a `DataGridView` smoothly, it's not because of the `ScrollBars`, it's because of **how the DataGridView renders its Cells**, normally we don't need such a smooth scrolling but I agree that it's needed in some cases.

Comment: @KingKing I am also sure it's possible because I want to do the same what is done when you grab the scrollbar and pull it down.

Comment: It's possible but it's too hard. In fact when you `scroll`, the `DataGridView` will get the info and render its `Rows` accordingly, it's designed to render rows so that the `First displayed row` should always start exactly at the top of the `ClientRectangle`. If you find how to do this, I'm happy to receive some notification from you. Again, it's too hard for `winforms`. I thought of this approach for you, you can add your grid to a `Panel`, layout your grid correctly and the `ScrollBar` of the panel will be used instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have dropped the need for DGV and therefore for this kind of approach. I have created a FlowLayoutPanel with Panels created dynamically to display the required data, designed the way I wanted it to be.

There is probably a way to perform smooth scrolling of DataGridView which could be accomplished by analyzing .NET reflection of DataGridView code, but again, I found an acceptable alternative and I'm using it.

There is a way to accomplish smooth scrolling of DGV by actually placing it on a panel with a scrollbar. That way, scrolling a panel scrolls the DGV too. This way wasn't convenient for me because DGV headers would get scrolled out of screen and I needed them to be visible at all times.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add your DGV to Panel

Comment: This helped me alot, adding the DGV to a panel solved scrolling issues.

Comment: Great an elegant solution, display the grid with all rows visible in the panel and put scroll bars on the panel. problem solved.