# Issue with dataGridView vertical scrolling

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a WinForms application which contains DataGridView with multiple lines. Now it all works fine till the number of lines a single cell increases and can no longer be displayed all at ones on the screen and since the DataGridView only allow Integral scrolling of rows it never shows the remaining of the line in the cells rather it just hops on to next row. So my question is that is there any way I can make the dataGridView to scroll rows in a non-integral way. Feel free to let me know if the question is not clear enough.

Comment: I.e. you want the scroll to be continuous rather than discrete?

Comment: Code for what exactly, it's a simple DataGridView with multiple lines in a single cell. Now if the total number of line in a single cell does not fit on screen then there is a problem. grid.DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True;
            grid.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells; Set these properties for DataGridView to show multiple lines. And then add lot of lines in it.

Comment: @G.LC yes that is correct I want it to be continous

Comment: Looking [at this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19413471/scrolling-datagridview-per-pixel) it seems not possible. But indeed you could make the dgv large enough for all rows, (provided this will keep the height < 32k pixels ) and put the dgv into a panel..