# How to make datagridview in C# scrolling slow - unable to view entire row content

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I'm unable to view the list of "Morning shift" employees list in a DGV.

I'm trying to create a week shifts DGV table but because I have a lot of names of employees in one shift (column: shift date , row: shift type), I can't see the total list of names in a shift cell (column: shift date , row: shift type), because of the total DGV height, so when I try to scroll down in order to see the rest of the "Morning" shift employees list, the dgv just goes down to the "Noon" row and shows me the list of the "Noon" employees.

All I'm after is that the DGV goes down slowly, I mean like a webpage and not as sharp as it is right now.

How do I do that?

I really hope that I'm clear, please tell me if I'm not...

Thank you very much.

Comment: I think what your looking for is Smooth Scrolling, or scrolling by pixel. In Winforms your limited to setting the number of rows scrolled by using the dgv's properties but this is still pretty sharp and doesn't resemble the webpage effect your after. May I suggest looking at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19413471/scrolling-datagridview-per-pixel) as an alternative solution. The OP appeared to solve his own problem by shifting to a FlowLayoutPanel and dynamically making the panels for it, this does somewhat support Smooth Scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

Set `AutoSize` property of the `DataGridView` to true and put in an auto-scroll container.

To set `AutoSize` property of `DataGridView` to true, use code:

```
dataGridView1.AutoSize = true;
```

For auto-scroll container, use the following panel control:

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
public class MyPanel : Panel
{
    protected override Point ScrollToControl(Control activeControl)
    {
        return this.AutoScrollPosition;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Reza,

Thank you for your help.

Can you please tell me how can I do that?

Right now, I took a panel from the tool box and placed it behind the shifts tables (2 tables - this week and next week's shifts), what do I need to do next? Should I type the code of the "auto-scroll container" in the program.cs file? or form.cs file? Thank you.

Comment: Hi @MasterSplinter 1. Create a `.cs` file in your project and paste above panel code in your class. 2. Close all designers and rebuild your project. 3. Open your form and drop an instance of `MyPanel` on the form and set it's `AutoScroll` property to `true`. 4. Drop your `DataGridView` in the panel and setup width of the `DataGridView` based on your requirement.  5. Handle `Load` event of the form and set `AutoSize` property of the `DataGridView` to `true` and load data into `DataGridView`.

Comment: Hi Reza, thank you for your help. It didn't work for me though :( I mean it has to work according to what you're saying by I couldn't get it to work.